# Calculus 7th Ed (Stewart) - Chapter 4 solution 2 page 332

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This can be really ridiculous for you but I can't understand why dx is up on the root in solution 2

Shouldn't be "du = root(2x+1)*dx" instead of what is show below?

[image: print]

Best Regards,

Comment: And also it is not `*dx`. `du/dx` is not a fraction; you can't just "multiply it to the other side".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u=\sqrt{2x+1}$, then the derivative is $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2x+1}} \cdot 2$, so the book is right.

Comment: Many thanks! I could understand well now.